$\int \frac{1}{1-x^2}dx$, which of the following solutions would be more appropriate?
So we did an integral in class that was basically of the form $\int \frac{1}{1-x^2}dx$, in class we did it with partial fractions, you get $\int \frac{1}{1-x^2}dx = \int \frac{1}{2}(\frac{1}{1-x} + \frac{1}{1+x})dx$ , which we can immediately integrate and we get: $\int \frac{1}{1-x^2}dx = \frac{1}{2}(-\ln\mid1-x\mid + \ln\mid1+x\mid) + C = \frac{1}{2}\ln\bigl|\frac{1+x}{1-x}\bigr| +C$.
Now, the teacher said in class that there was another way of doing it, since as it turns out the integrand is precisely the derivative of the inverse hyperbolic tangent, so we can integrate immediately and we get: $\int \frac{1}{1-x^2}dx = \tanh^{-1} (x) + C = \frac{1}{2}\ln\frac{1+x}{1-x} +C$.
This two results look similar, however notice the lack of absolute value on the second answer, in fact the inverse hyperbolic tangent is only defined for $-1 < x < 1$. The integrand is defined on all values except for $\{-1, 1\}$ and the antiderivative that we computed with partial fractions is also defined for those exact same values. However if we do it the second way, the antiderivative is only defined for $-1 < x < 1$, so does that mean that it is technically an incorrect or incomplete answer?

@Dr.Mathva Thanks! I suspected that would be the case. I do wonder, what about cases where the function is defined on a domain $D$ but the antiderivative only exists for a proper subset of $D$? Kind of what happens with derivatives which not always exist for the entire domain of the function. In those cases, would be require the antiderivative to be defined on the greatest number of points on $D$ where the antiderivative does exist?

If the antiderivative or any antiderivative only exists for a proper subset of $~D,~$ then part of the answer is that the integral is undefined outside of this subset.  If (instead) a different antiderivative exists for the portion of $~D~$ outside of the proper subset, then the answer must specify this.

@zlaaemi Say you have $f:S\to \mathbb{R}$. If there exists no $F:S\to \mathbb{R}$ such that $F'=f$ on $S$, then $f$ does not have an antiderivative (for this choice of domain $S$). Of course one has to be careful with the properties of $S$: If, for example, $S$ weren't to be open, say $S=[0,1]$, the usual definition of derivative would not make sense for those points with no neighborhoods (here: $0$ and $1$). There are notions as one-sided-derivative you could use here, but I guess there is no general convention for these cases.

Re my previous comment, Dr. Mathva's subsequent comment raises an issue of the derivative at the endpoints, that I was totally oblivious to.

@Dr.Mathva I see, so since there's no convention, would it be valid if I said that functions defined on a closed interval as their domain, don't have antiderivative? Since there is no function that has a two sided derivative on that domain.

@zlaaemi I think so, but if you're going to use it for example when handing in solutions or so, it'd definitely be worth explaining why this fails to be the case.

One usually requires the antiderivative to be defined over the same set as the original function (see here for a more detailed discussion). So, technically, it depends on whether you are taking $f: (-1,1)\to \mathbb{R}, x\mapsto \frac1{1-x^2}$ or, for instance, $f: (0,1)\cup (1,\infty)\to \mathbb{R}$. Your first option is an antiderivative for both domains (although it could be more general for the second domain), while the second option only works for the same domain as it is not defined outside of $(-1, 1)$.
Also, remember that if the original function can only be defined over certain subsets of $\mathbb{R}$, the space of antiderivatives gains one "dimension" per connected component. Take your example with $f:\mathbb{R}\setminus \{-1, 1\}\to \mathbb{R}, x\mapsto \frac1{1-x^2}$ and notice the domain (which is the biggest domain where you can define the function) has three connected components. In this case $$F:\mathbb{R}\setminus \{-1, 1\}\to \mathbb{R}, x\mapsto \begin{cases}\frac12\ln{\left|\frac{1+x}{1-x}\right|}+C_1, \qquad \text{if }\;x\in(-\infty,-1)\\
\frac12\ln{\left|\frac{1+x}{1-x}\right|}+C_2, \qquad \text{if }\;x\in(-1,1)\\
\frac12\ln{\left|\frac{1+x}{1-x}\right|}+C_3, \qquad \text{if }\;x\in(1, \infty)\end{cases}$$
for some constants $C_i\in \mathbb{R}$ is a valid antiderivative too.
If you take $n$ pairwise disjoint subsets $S_1, \ldots, S_n\subset \mathbb{R}$ and consider $f:\bigcup_{i=1}^nS_i\to \mathbb{R}, x\mapsto \frac1{1-x^2}$, you would obtain a similar $F$ depending on $n$ constants $C_1, \ldots, C_n$.
In other words: The domain matters!

Thanks for your reply, however I don't understand why would I have $n$ constants $C_i$, shouldn't all of the components use the same constant?

@zlaaemi Take the $F$ I have constructed, say with $C_1=1$, $C_2=2$ and $C_3=3$. Is this function differentiable over $\mathbb{R}\setminus {\pm 1}$? Is it the case that $F'=f$ in $\mathbb{R}\setminus{\pm1}$? Take the definitions and confirm whether these claims hold or not :D

Yes, I see that it is an antiderivative by definition, what concerns me is the fact that we can then use this to essentially generate a bunch of antiderivatives that we previously didn't have. When we say that $\int \frac{1}{x \sqrt{x^2-1}}dx = \sec^{-1}(\mid x \mid)+C$ we have found some antiderivatives, but not all, since we can split up the domain into $x < -1$ and $x > 1$ and so a new antiderivative not included in $\sec^{-1}(\mid x \mid)+C$ is $\sec^{-1}(\mid x \mid)+5$ if $x < -1$ and $\sec^{-1}(\mid x \mid)+20$ if $x > 1$. I thought adding the $+C$ meant we had all antiderivatives.

@zlaaemi Yeah, that is precisely the problem when introducing the constant $C$, that it is actually just locally constant. I am not quite sure why integration is taught omitting this detail (and, therefore, actually making a wrong statement)... I guess it's just simpler. Have a look here.
